# Modify selector in redux saga without mutating state

Tags: redux, redux-saga, mutable

When using a selector, I thought that I could do whatever I wanted with the variable without modifying the state, so I was surprised that the state became mutated.

So if this is wrong (in a redux saga):

```
const filters = yield select(state => state.filters.filters);

filters.terms['helloo'] = "mutated";

//send data with request
yield put(requestData(filters)
```

How come that first line is a direct reference to the state?

Anyway, if I try using `Object.assign`, it also mutates state:

```
const filters = Object.assign({}, yield select(state => state.filters.filters));
filters.terms['helloo'] = "mutated";
```

How do I create a selection that is a copy of the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's truly no "magic" involved here.  Redux's `getState()` is literally just `return state`, and both hand-written selectors and Reselect return whatever *you* have written the functions to return.  So, in that example, `filters` is the actual object reference that's nested inside the store state, because that's what *your* function returned.

Per the [Redux docs page on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns), you need to copy *all* levels of nesting that you want to update.  In your example, you're making a copy of `filters`, but not `filters.terms`, so `terms` is also still the original object that's in the store.  You would need to make a copy of that as well, and modify the copy.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm understanding a bit more even if it's not crystal clear. In the reducers, you return the state which you modified, but not in a saga, so I didn't think I could change state directly like that.. but I made a copy of filters.terms and put it in an object declaratively (if that's the right term) and that worked.. but Ill take a look at that link.

Comment: I'd also suggest reading [Immutability in React and Redux: The Complete Guide](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/) as well.  Again, the key issue here is that in both the reducer and selectors, you have references to the "real" original objects that are in the store.  It's important to understand that.  So, when you mutate one of those objects, you've mutated the original data.

Comment: @markerikson thanks, me to trying this, where could the cloning of the Redux state happen, In the Saga it self after `getState()` return with whatever state I need and then do `Object.assign` shallow copy(if enough). Or should I do this in the selector `createSelector` like creating a `selectCloneSelectorOfSomeState` specialised selector that return a state clone pease?

Comment: @Kid  Entirely depends on what you're trying to do. Typically you should avoid copying state by default, and only copy it at the point where you need to do something with it (ie, in a reducer, or possibly in an action creator if you're updating it to send to a server or something).